# jquery mobile site on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile

When I load my site up on my iPhone it doesn't show the site. It only shows this ">".
It works fine on the computer and my iPad. Any ideas what it could be?

The mobile app is at http://yourguest.co.uk/iphone/app/first.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div data-role="page" id="page8">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Sunday  </h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
    <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London">Directions to here</a>   
</div>
    <div data-role="footer">

        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>







> // This is out of place. Maybe the IPhone cannot handle jQuery mobile's pages
  // with this content outside the pages.

</body>
```

Comment: I'm also seeing some funkiness between lines 191-202 of the source where there's a </div followed by a bunch of empty lines and then the closing >.

Comment: This is weird, but shouldn't be a problem. `</div>` `< /div>`and `</div  >` should all be valid tags, because whitespace shouldn't be relevant.